# Executing Gulp task(s) only when publishing ASP.NET 5 web application

Tags: .net, gulp, publish, asp.net-core, dnu

What would be the best way to execute Gulp tasks only when publishing an ASP.NET 5 web application? Do I need to [add a custom build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293663.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that executes a Gulp command?

```
cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\Projects\ProjectName\Source\ProjectName.Web" --gulpfile "C:\Projects\ProjectName\Source\ProjectName.Web\Gulpfile.js" publish
```

Or, preferably, is there a way to bind a Gulp task to the `BeforePublish` target via the Task Runner Explorer?

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**
.NET Core CLI doesn't support "prepack" any more. A "postcompile" script may work better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts

**Original Answer**

Add it to your "scripts" section of `project.json`

[project.json: Scripts documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#scripts)

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "gulp publish",
  }
...
}
```

Comment: If I wanted it to run before a publish, would I hook into the `prepack` action?

Comment: Actually, the "prebuild" target may be better if you are using VS tooling to publish.

Comment: if you want to run before publish then I think `prepublish` is the action to use...

Answer (score 7):

Create the target in your publish profile file (the *.pubxml file still exists in asp.net 5 projects). The pubxml file is a build file and it is added to your proj build file. This way it would only be ran when you publish using that specific profile.
I would use BeforeBuild target to be more generic (all the packages restore, all the injection of js/css in views etc I would do them before the build would start) and add there the gulp command:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
   <Exec Command="call gulp" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

This would work no matter if you publish from Visual Studio or with MSBuild from your build machine.